# How do I change O365 bar Colour?

Tags: sharepoint-online

On one site collection only i want to change the office bar at the different  color is this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply suite bar settings to all apps under O365 tenant you can update theme settings from the Admin center. Here is a link for instructions.

https://www.eliostruyf.com/how-to-apply-a-new-suite-bar-theme-on-your-office-365-tenant/

Thanks,
Venkat Konjeti

Answer (score 2):

The following styles should allow you to change the color of the suite bar:

```
.o365spo.o365cst.o365cs-base .o365cs-topnavBGColor {
    background-color: #000000 !important;    
}
```

Find more on customizing the suite bar [here](https://blog.rickzeleznik.com/2014/09/09/css-reference-sharepoint-online-office-365-suite-bar/).

Comment: I have over 10 subsites under it also, which will mean editing a lot of pages. Is there a way of just doing it from the root of the site collection and letting it cascade all the way down?

Comment: Do they all use the same master page as the root site? If so, then just update hte master page there, and it'll reflect in all subsites.

Comment: nope  they have there own and I have changed it
manually but need to hide the office 365 etc bits.

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll have to update them individually.  You could have them all point to a common CSS file, and then in the future, you just have to update that file instead of all the master pages.